# Read only permissions on AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to create user who is going to see all the user profile and group profiles but should not having access to changes or delete any thing on AS400 machine.

To achieve this i have created User having following permissions-

```
User class         - *SECADM
Special Authority  - *ALLOBJ, *SECADM.
```

By creating this type of user can we achieve only read-only access for this.
IBMi version - V7R1 and V7R2

My main requirement is to create a user having very minimum permissions means who can only read data from IBMi machine and do not have capability to change any thing.

If any one is having any idea about this please share.

Comment: No. A user with *ALLOBJ may obtain any other desired authority. Only a very few users (less than 10 on a large system) should have *ALLOBJ (and possibly any other special authority). Use adopted authority instead to view *USRPRF objects.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to create read only user

Comment: Create a program consisting of essentially nothing but DSPUSRPRF ??USRPRF() and compiled as USRPRF(*OWNER). Assign ownership to one of your site's user profiles that has authority to all *USRPRF objects that you want covered. (Not owned by QSECOFR nor any IBM-supplied profile.) Then grant *USE authority to your "read-only user" and give no other unnecessary authorities.

Comment: @user2338816, maybe this should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: i am not that much familiar with as400 system. Can u tell me what u want say about that program.

Comment: minus *secadm     @user2338816 enter an answer.

Comment: ADDAUTLE is working if i remove *SECADM authority because *ALLOBJ is their.

Comment: Creation of a single-line CL program is almost a fundamental requirement for someone who needs to manage security. Can you edit your question to describe your background on the platform? An "answer" will need to fit your circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

`*ALLOBJ` is a very powerful special authority on IBM i and allows a user to change or delete nearly everything on IBM i.

> From the IBM i [Security manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarl/rzarlallobjsa.htm) (v7.3):
>
> **Risks:** *ALLOBJ special authority gives the user extensive authority over all resources on the system. The user can view, change, or delete any object. The user can also grant to other users the authority to use objects.

`*SECADM` is a very specific special authority on IBM i, it allows a user to create, change, and delete user profiles. Probably not something you want a regular user to be able to do. Should be tightly controlled.

User classes are mostly meaningless any more as it only controls menu access. Menu based authorities were useful back in the day when the AS400 was typically a standalone system or networked only with other AS400's.

> Note: I use AS400 here as it was the name of the whole system (hardware and OS) back in the day, current naming on new hardware is complex, but IBM i is the name of the OS previously known as OS/400

One way to solve your problem, as *user2338816* indicated in his comments, is to create a CL program `MYGETUSER` that contains a single command `DSPUSRPRF` or `RTVUSRPRF` depending on what you want to do with the information. If you want all the user profile info displayed on the screen by the command, use `DSPUSRPRF`. If you want to retrieve specific user profile attributes to the calling program, use `RTVUSRPRF`. Your CL program `MYGETUSER` needs to be compiled with `USRPRF(*OWNER)` and it must be owned by a user profile that has `*READ` authority to all the user profiles you want to be able to display. You may be able to collect these user profiles in an authorization list to avoid having to assign private authorities to everything. Now you can assign `*USE` authority to the CL program `MYGETUSER` for any user that has the need to view user profiles, or the user profile attributes surfaced by your CL program.

**Notes:** Be sure to assign only the bare minimum authorities to the owner of your CL program to get the information you need, and only give access to that program to the users that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, depending on the object too. If they don't have object authority to the object, they can't access it. You would have to GRTOBJAUT.

Comment: Not needed with appropriate adopted authority.